# Push Ionic2 to heroku : Cannot get /

Tags: heroku, deployment, ionic2

I'm trying to push my ionic2 project (as a web-app) to Heroku, the deploy is ok, but when I'm accessing to the app, I have a blank page with a "Cannot GET /".

I have an express server, a correct Procfile, but I think the www/ is not build on deploy. Effectively, if I include my www/ folder in my push, the web-app run... (But i don't want versionning my www/ folder).

Here, my package.json. What i'm doing wrong ? Thank you !

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.27",
    "auth0-lock": "^10.7.3",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.11",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^1.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.9",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "deals: An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: "postinstall": "ionic-app-scripts build" has resolved my problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved me! :D